# React how do I multi-map values for efficiency

Tags: arrays, reactjs, mapping

I have a look up array that maps a color against a value. The value coming in can be from more than one property e.g.

```
const data = {
  status4Weeks: "2",
  status8Weeks: "3",
  status12Weeks: "4"
};
```

My look up will find the value e.g "4" and give 4 an assigned color. Currently I have had to write 3 identical mappings for the 3 properties. I need to do some sort of mapping that looks at the key, assign the color and map this into the UI. My UI is also duplicated 3 times.

```
const COLORS = {
  one: "#4caf50",
  two: "#81c784",
  three: "#ffee58",
  four: "#FFC107",
  five: "#ff7043",
  six: "#f44336",
  seven: "#455a64"
};

const status4WeeksColor = [
  data.status4Weeks === "1"
    ? COLORS.one
    : data.status4Weeks === "2"
    ? COLORS.two
    : data.status4Weeks === "3"
    ? COLORS.three
    : data.status4Weeks === "4"
    ? COLORS.four
    : data.status4Weeks === "5"
    ? COLORS.five
    : data.status4Weeks === "6"
    ? COLORS.six
    : data.status4Weeks === "7"
    ? COLORS.seven
    : COLORS.seven
];
```

Duplication below for the other two properties...

```
const status8WeeksColor = [
  data.status8Weeks === "1"
    ? COLORS.one
    : data.status8Weeks === "2"
    ? COLORS.two
    : data.status8Weeks === "3"
    ? COLORS.three
    : data.status8Weeks === "4"
    ? COLORS.four
    : data.status8Weeks === "5"
    ? COLORS.five
    : data.status8Weeks === "6"
    ? COLORS.six
    : data.status8Weeks === "7"
    ? COLORS.seven
    : COLORS.seven
];

const status12WeeksColor = [
  data.status12Weeks === "1"
    ? COLORS.one
    : data.status12Weeks === "2"
    ? COLORS.two
    : data.status12Weeks === "3"
    ? COLORS.three
    : data.status12Weeks === "4"
    ? COLORS.four
    : data.status12Weeks === "5"
    ? COLORS.five
    : data.status12Weeks === "6"
    ? COLORS.six
    : data.status12Weeks === "7"
    ? COLORS.seven
    : COLORS.seven
];
```

See my codesandbox for the complete code: https://codesandbox.io/s/pj0yk6z91x

There is far too much code on this page than required I'm sure!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the way colors are mapped: instead of using word property names, you can use string-numeric values, like:

```
const COLORS = {
  '1': "#4caf50",
  '2': "#81c784",
  '3': "#ffee58",
  '4': "#FFC107",
  '5': "#ff7043",
  '6': "#f44336",
  '7': "#455a64"
}
```

This way you can access it with just:

```
const status4WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status4Weeks]
// or const status8WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status8Weeks]
// or const status12WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status12Weeks]
```

If you then need a default value, you can do something like:

```
const DEFAULT = '7'
const status4WeeksColor = COLORS[data.status4Weeks] || COLORS[DEFAULT]
```

With this kind of access, you can easily map your arrays.